# EGOTableViewPullRefresh and landscape orientation

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4, iphone-sdk-3.0, landscape

I am using Cocoanetic's implementation of `EGOTableViewPullRefresh`.
It's a cinch to implement.  Love it:

- http://www.cocoanetics.com/2009/12/how-to-make-a-pull-to-reload-tableview-just-like-tweetie-2/

The only problem I'm having is with rotation.  When the view rotates, the refresh header doesn't adjust for landscape mode.  It sits left aligned, 320.0f units wide.

[image]

I have tried everything I can think of to adjust this properly.  I set it as a property in `PullToRefreshTableViewController` and tried to set the frame the same way it is done in init.  This failed.  I tried to do it in this same controller in `viewWillAppear`.  Failed.

Beyond this, I tried about 6 other methods not worth detailing.  The problem seems to be that I'm using the wrong bounds, even though I'm making them relative to the view.

Nothing I do replicates what is seemingly easy in `viewDidLoad`:

```
refreshHeaderView = [[EGORefreshTableHeaderView alloc] initWithFrame:
                         CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f - self.view.bounds.size.height,
                                    320.0f, self.view.bounds.size.height)];
```

It seems all I really need to do is increase the width. I tried something along the lines of this:

```
refreshHeaderView.frame = CGRectMake(refreshHeaderView.frame.origin.x, refreshHeaderView.frame.origin.y, 480.0f, refreshHeaderView.frame.size.height);
```

No luck.

The link at the top has the full, unmodified source code for what I'm using.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about just setting the [`UIView.autoresizingMask`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006816-CH3-SW6) to `UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth`?

Comment: Didn't work. I set this in viewDidLoad.  I tried both the PullToRefresh super class and my child class. Anything else I need to do make this technique work?

Comment: Scratch that.  It works fine.  I just had to apply to it to each label/image/etc on `refreshHeaderView` including directly to `refreshHeaderView`.  Thanks for your help!